# php uploaded filename changes

Tags: php, html, upload

I need help about uploading multiple file with php. When i upload a file with different character name, it changes file name, for example if its `"Kayıt.doc"` after upload it changes to `"KayÄ±t.doc"`. I dont want this happen, what can i do? Please help.... :)

This is html page....

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>  
    <form action="cvupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
        <table width="539" height="75" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="220"><div align="right">Step 2 : </div></td>
                <td width="309">Please upload your cv now </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="style14">Submit your cv (ms word / zip format)</span></td>
                <td><label for="file"></label>
                <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><label for="Submit"></label>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is PHP page...

```
<?php

$toplam = count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $toplam; $i++)
{
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename)
    {


 if (((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == "application/msword")||($_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == "application/zip")))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] > 0))
   {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0)
     {

     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] . "<br />";
     }
   else
     {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . "<br />";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] . "<br />";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i] . "<br />";

     if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]))
       {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " already exists. ";
       }
     else
       {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],
       "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
       }
     }   
   }
 else
   {
   echo "Invalid file";

   }
}
 ?>
```

When i use without brackets like this `<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />`  for just 1 file its ok but for multiple file it doesnt work.

Comment: uploaded file name contains accent characters? if so use `utf8encode()` or `utf8decode()`

Comment: You shouldn't use the original file name when you generate the destination file path; consider giving it a unique id instead and only use the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your replies, i changed code like this and it worked.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], "upload/" . iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9//TRANSLIT",$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess its not problem of your code. i guess your pc doesnt support some character encoding.

```
<?php
  function utf8_urldecode($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
    return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
  }
```

refer this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am reading, the URI that you are receiving in php is encoded. Try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php on the string in question.

Hope this helps.